# Xamarin: How to add an item to a existing group in a CollectionView

Tags: xamarin, runtime, grouping, addition, collectionview

I have the following CollectionView:

```html
<CollectionView  IsGrouped="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyGroup}"> 
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
      </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <Label  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And then I have the following Model for my group:

```
 public ItemGroupModel(String name, ObservableCollection<ItemModel> itemModels):base(itemModels)
    {
        this.Name = name;
       
    }
    public String Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

In my ViewModel I have the property which I called in my CollectionView:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ShopingItemModel> MyItems { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<ItemGroupModel> myGroup;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemGroupModel> MyGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return myGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            myGroup= value;
        }
    }
```

Now I have no idea how I can add items to an existing group.
If I initialize the Propery named MyGroup I have for example a group named "GroupX" and have added Items in it named "ItemA,ItemB and ItemC" then I will see them in my view.

But how can I add Items to a existing group at a later time when I run my app in runtime? Is there a way to do that?
Because I don't have access to the ObservableCollection in the constructor of ItemGroupModel named itemModels.

Comment: `MyGroup[0].Add(new ShopingItemModel { ... });`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This was helpful and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

just find the correct group, then add an item to it

```
MyGroup[0].Add(new ShopingItemModel { ... });
```

you could also use LINQ to find a specific group by name, and then add to it